# Pass a string from DidSelectRowAtIndexPath to a button-click action

Tags: iphone

I have this code
NSString *localStringValue;

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    localStringValue = [m_textfield cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.text; 
    localStringValue = [m_textfield cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].detailTextLabel.text; 
    NSArray* toReload = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: indexPath, self.selectedIndexPath, nil];
    self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
    if ([[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark){
        UploadView *uploadview = (UploadView *)self.view;
        if (uploadview != nil)
        {
            [m_owner uploadString:localStringValue];
            //[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }

        [[m_textfield cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    }

    else {

        [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];

    }
}
```

in this code i am syncing localStringValue to google-doc when i tap the cell if the check mark is there.localStringValue contains the values in the tableview cell.Every thing works fine at this point.But my need is i want to pass this value to a button click,that means if the user select multiple row i want all the values in the localStringValue and pass this through this code

```
- (IBAction)doUpload:(id)sender
{
            UploadView *uploadview = (UploadView *)self.view;
            if (uploadview != nil)
            {
                [m_owner uploadString:@""];
                //[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            }

}
```

i want to pass localstringvalue in `[m_owner uploadString:localstringvalue];`
How to do this?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a `NSMutableArray` as class variable and you can add your strings to that on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. Later on on button click you can process the `NSMutableArray` to fetch strings one by one and sending them to google-doc...etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update ur

```
- (void)doUpload:(NSString*)stringValue
{
            UploadView *uploadview = (UploadView *)self.view;
            if (uploadview != nil)
            {
                [m_owner uploadString:localstringvalue];
                //[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            }
}
```

And one more thing 
`localStringValue = [m_textfield cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.text`  // reassigning the string again so this line does not make any sense.

Comment: it shows errors "interface type string cannot be passed by value "did you forget NSString" this is my error and undeclared localstring